# Infinite process

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm creating an rails app, which scraps few website's contents. Let's say - 15 shops and their products. THat scraping is a infinite process which scraps each shop one by one and when the last shop is scrapped, worker goes back to the first one and the whole process starts from the beginning.

My first thought was to use kind of recursive sidekiq worker which would scrap a shop no. 1 and after a success, scraps a next shop fireing itself

```
class FetcherWorker
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(shop_id)
    Shop.find(shop_id).fetch_products

    FetcherWorker.perform_async(next_shop_id)
  end
end
```

However, i have absolutely no experience on that ground (such long-running processes) so i wanted to ask you if there is any best-practive or any obvious solution i should use in a following situation? It's quite important for me to be able to access an info what's currently going on and which shop is currently beeing scrapped (and sidekiq provides such tools). Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not just do it daily on a schedule. Or at a push hourly. Certainly not immediately after scraping the list. Seriously, how often do you expect them to be adding new products? I'd take a look at the `whenever` gem if I were you.

Comment: +1 ^^ There is also the [sidetiq](https://github.com/tobiassvn/sidetiq) gem

Comment: Why scrape them one by one? Is there a dependency? Launch several together if you can.

Comment: actually i'm currently on a product discovery phase and don't know how to approach that yet. But yeah, cron job that checks if there are any shops to be fetched (each shop has a different treshold) and if so, adds them to sidekiq queue sounds pretty reasonable. Thank you guys!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would separate performing the work and scheduling it. 
If your job crashes then it might not reschedule itself. Also there is a bootstrap issue (let's say on restart) so you would need to schedule the first job somehow.

I'd probably add a last_scraped_at timestamp to the shop model and add a scope :up_for_scraping which finds all the shops that have not been scraped for N-minutes.

Then a scheduler finds those shops and queues them in sidekiq for execution. The scheduler can be something simple as a ruby script which is triggered by cron to start with.

Perhaps you can make your jobs so that they don't run multiple times for the same shop?

```
def perform...
   return if runs_or_has_been_running_within_a_short_period_for_this_shop?
   ...
   ...
end
```

This should help to not pile up more work than your worker pool can handle. The number of jobs queued should stay about the same over time. If it piles up: either your scraping code is not performant enough , you don't have enough actors, the scraping frequency is to high, or there is not enough hardware. If it is empty then you can scrape more often.